# Connection pool related errors when running JUnit 5 tests in parallel

Tags: java, junit5, spring-test, hikaricp

I've enabled parallel JUnit tests using the following properties:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true

junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent

junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy = fixed
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism = 8
```

I'm observing some weird behavior with the DB connections. Following is the exceptions that I'm getting:

```
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (springHikariCP) has been closed.
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:96)
```

My hikariCP config bean looks like this

```xml
    <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP"/>
        <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${spring.datasource.url}"/>
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="24"/>
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="10000"/>
        <property name="transactionIsolation" value="TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED"/>
    </bean>
```

What could be the reason for these exceptions? (I'm not seeing these exceptions and the tests are passing when I don't make the tests parallel)
Is there any specific thing that I should do, specifically with the connection pool, to make it function properly with in concurrent setup as well?

Comment: Probably I'm hitting this: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/811

Comment: it most probably has to do with the general setup of the test. nothing of what you posted gives any indication on what the issue is. without knowing the code of the test class it is not possible to answer this question correctly. everything would be speculation